# Win32 time diff calculation in windows failover cluster

Tags: c++, c, winapi

We do use [GetTickCount64()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411(v=vs.85).aspx) for calculating the elapsed time between two events. This is fine as long as the application runs on the same Server.

What happens with GetTickCount64() when the application is transfered to an other node of the windows failover cluster?

Do we still get the uptime of the first node?

Is GetTickCount64() fail over cluster aware?

What better time measurement we could use in a windows failover cluster environment so that the application time difference calculation is not affected when moved to an other node?

And most important: If a user or the a time keeping service adjusts the PC time the application must not be affected by this time change. This is why the idea with GetTickCount64() seems to be good but addionally the application must by cluster aware.

Comment: Assuming that the nodes have their times in sync (which I think they should), you could use [\[MS.Docs\]: GetSystemTimeAsFileTime function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.140)). `GetTickCount64` is machine based (or at least so I think).

Comment: Posting code used to  determine  the difference noted in "Win32 time diff calculation in windows failover cluster" would add clarity to these questions.

Comment: Sorry there is no Code at this time. The application has to Support about 1000 timers. This timers must also work correctly when the running app is moved to an other cluster node. When the app asks for the time it must get the same time for calculation of the elapsed time. We are looking for a failover cluster aware elapsed time calculation programming.

Comment: from the API description: "Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started."  I don't think this can be synchronized across machines.